# Use JInput to get all POST / GET vars

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput

Is there a way to get all the `POST` or `GET` vars at once using `JInput`? Something like this, only using the newer syntax:

```
$post = JRequest::get('post');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by using **JInput**.

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$jform = $input->get('jform', array(), 'ARRAY'); 
print_r($jform);
//$jform will show all the data of your form
?>
```

Please refer this document for more details:

> https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: @Ruchika-- thanks. Will that get either the `GET` or `POST` vars? or would you use `$input->post('jform', array(), 'ARRAY')` to get the `POST` payload?

Comment: it will get all the vars. Also, please check other answers as well as the question has been marked duplicate and already has answers else modify your question as it is stated